# How do I troubleshoot a zshrc file stuck with settings added using `code ~/zshrc.`

Tags: terminal

I used `code ~/zshrc.` to go into the file and do some custom styling for my terminal. One of those things I added was `echo -e " \e[5m \e[25m"` which causes my command line to blink if I haven't initialized git tracking. I did it just for fun and decided after pressing cmd + q in vs code that I wanted to change it. However, this was lost and now when I run `code ~/zshrc.` it brings me to a blank file with none of the settings I personally added. When I did this I was definitely in my home directory. I'm wondering if there is any way I can undo some changes, go back to the way it was on a previous day, or just reset. Any recommendations? My terminal is not usable with everything flashing. Even running `ls` all my directories are flashing and I can hardly read it.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post an update. After a break, I came back the next day and noticed that the command I should've been running was `code ~/.zshrc` and **not** `code ~/zshrc.`. That fixed the whole problem so I could edit my `zshrc` file.